# How do I learn to be a GM?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, encounter-design, new-gm, story

I have never played Pathfinder before or D&D. My friends and I started a trial run with various characters that they made and I have been directed into the GMing position. Yet I have no idea what I’m doing. I don't know how exactly to create NPCs or “enemies”.

My players are wanting an overall story arc (and I feel like they are expecting a lot from me, a beginner, because they have listened to The Adventure Zone podcast) and I don’t know what to do or how to create a story arc at all.

How to I learn to GM this game? How can I learn what I don’t even know I need to know?

Comment: Simply asking for general tips and tricks to GMing seems too broad a question to be answerable on a Q&A forum like RPG.SE. If you have any specific questions, we can probably answer those, however. It seems like your two questions could each be split into their own questions, and you could elaborate on what exactly you're habing trouble with when it comes to creating NPCs/enemies and when it comes to creating stories. It might also be helpful to search here to see if such questions have been asked already (I haven't checked myself, but I imagine they have).

Comment: I gave this an edit to make the question after your situation description both fit your situation and be a type of question we can help with. Is this version of your question still useful to you?